# Is the Access token in the Amadeus test developers in only set to 30 min?

Tags: php, amadeus

Im currently creating a travel agency website, and i use Amadeus for searching low fare prices etc. but everytime the access token expired in 30min. i get status 401 (the access token is expired). And repeatingly request another access token thru their website and paste it to my codes. May i ask , if there is a solution so that it will automatically change my access token in my codes

i currently using this codes to request access codes

**

```
$url = "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token";
$curls = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={apikey}&client_secret={apisecret}');
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
$token = curl_exec($curls);
curl_close($curls);
$tokenresult = json_decode($token,true);
print_r ($tokenresult);
```

**

but everytime i refresh my website it will also display

```
"type": "amadeusOAuth2Token",
            "username": "",
            "application_name": "Thesis",
            "client_id": "",
            "token_type": "Bearer",
            "access_token": "*****",
            "expires_in": 1799,
            "state": "approved",
            "scope": ""
```

which is very annoying.

and this is my code using the access_token

```
$ch = curl_init("https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers?origin=$client_flyingfrom&destination=$client_flyingto&departureDate=$client_departing&returnDate=$client_returning&nonStop=false&currency=PHP&max=2");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
   'Content-Type: application/json',
   'Authorization: Bearer *****' 
   ));
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json = json_decode($data,true);
print_r($json);
```

Can you help me? is there a way to automatically change my access token without copy and pasting new access tokens in my codes? thanks alot guys

Comment: You just posted your API token, you should change/revoke it immediately.

Comment: rtfm: https://developers.amadeus.com/

Comment: thanks @AlexHowansky but it is only set to 30 min btw. im just asking if there is a way to obtain new access token without copy and paste in my code.

Comment: You could write a simple check, if the request returns unauthorized, get a new token, aka refresh the token and perform the request again with the new token.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a guide [here](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/developer-guides/blob/master/guides/authorization.md) helping you to implement the oauth2 authorization process.

The token has a time to live of 30min but you can request a new token at any time (no need to go through the portal, you have an API for this). The one on the portal is actually there only to let you play with the APIs without writing code.

The first code you posted is implementing the oauth2 process to get the access_token, you just need to call this every 30min to get a new one (or even before - up to you).
From this call, you save the access_token and you add it in the header on your next API calls (explained in the guide).

It prints it in your website because of this line

> print_r ($tokenresult)